# Why doesn't numpy random reshuffle work on a numpy array?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, random, shuffle

Here is my sample code:

```
ah = np.linspace(1, 20, 20)
print(ah)
>>> [  1.   2.   3.   4.   5.   6.   7.   8.   9.  10.  11.  12.  13.  14.  15.
      16.  17.  18.  19.  20.]

print(np.random.shuffle(ah))
>>> None
```

[According to the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html), the input should be an array or a list. Why doesn't the sample code above work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reshuffle is inplace, the reshuffle function does not return anything:

#### Test Code:

```
ah = np.linspace(1, 20, 20)
print(ah)
print(np.random.shuffle(ah))
print(ah)
```

#### Results:

```
[  1.   2.   3.   4.   5.   6.   7.   8.   9.  10.  11.  12.  13.  14.  15.
  16.  17.  18.  19.  20.]

None

[  5.  15.  13.   8.   1.   2.  18.   7.  14.   4.  10.   6.  17.  11.  16.
  19.  12.   3.  20.   9.]
```